# How can I add operator definition to an existing struct from a header file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hashmap, operator-overloading

I am developing a `SNMP Agent` in Windows. In the header file `snmp.h` there is a `struct` which defines the `OID` identifier for a value and the definition for that is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  UINT   idLength;
  UINT * ids;
} AsnObjectIdentifier;
```

I want to use this `AsnObjectIdentifier` as a key to an `unordered_map` but the `struct` definition does not overload the `==` operator, which brings me to the question whether if it is possible to add an operator overload to an already defined `struct` or would I have to just have my custom `struct` wrapping the `AsnObjectIdentifier` variable.

Comment: That's what inheritance is for

Comment: @stark I was not preferring to change types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use custom functor in your `unordered_map` declaration.

Indeed, [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) provides custom template arguments for this purpose.

**Note**: you need to provide a functor to compute the hash value too for `unordered_map`.

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Hash = std::hash<Key>,   // <----- You need hash for Key
    class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>, // <---- Equal Functor
    // ...
```

Just define your functor in accordance with the logic of your program. Something like:

```
struct AsnObjectIdentifierHasher {
  std::size_t operator()(const AsnObjectIdentifier&) const noexcept;
};

struct AsnObjectIdentifierComparator {
  bool operator()(const AsnObjectIdentifier&, 
                  const AsnObjectIdentifier&) const noexcept;
};

template <typename T>
using HashMap = std::unordered_map<AsnObjectIdentifier, 
                                   T, 
                                   AsnObjectIdentifierHasher, 
                                   AsnObjectIdentifierComparator>;
```

---

I strongly discourage the usage of a *free-function* to implement arithmetic and logical operators (especially when STL interface provides customization by means of template arguments). *Functors* (function objects) provide better isolation code and avoid scope problems (e.g., ADL).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can define operators outside of the class:

```
bool operator==(AsnObjectIdentifier const& lhs, AsnObjectIdentifier const& rhs)
{
    return /* whatever */;
}
```

Alternatively you can define a custom equality function object and pass it to `unordered_map`'s fourth template parameter.

Comment: outside of class or struct? Where should I define this function - in which namespace or more appropriately where to organize this function in project structure? I think passing a custom equality function would be a better fit for me as I don't want to change types with inheritance.

Comment: This is just a regular global function that doesn't belong to any class/struct. Define it outside of any class, preferably in the same namespace the struct is in.

Comment: Inheritance should NOT be used for this sort of thing. That comment was wrong.

Comment: @Pubby If you don't put it in the same namespace as the class it operates on, ADL will bite you hard sooner or later. And if that namespace is not yours to add things into, that's a problem.